# No adapter attached in recyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

It gives me a blank activity and not showing my list in it .. i don't know what is the error.Any one who can help ?
Here is my code:

```
    public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeCallBack {

    public ArrayList<info> info;
    private  Adaptor myadaptor;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);

        BackgroundHome backgroundHome=new BackgroundHome(this,this);
        backgroundHome.execute();


    }

    @Override
    public void processData(JSONArray data)
    {

        JSONObject js;

                if(data!=null)
                {
                     info=new ArrayList<>();

                    try
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++)
                        {
                            js =data.getJSONObject(i);
                            info in=new info(js.getString("Names"),js.getString("city"),js.getString("university"));
                            info.add( in);




                        }



                        myadaptor=new Adaptor(info);

                        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter( myadaptor);
```

It gives me an error and app stop when i call recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter) in on create method.
Here is my adaptor code:

```
public class Adaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptor.ViewHolder> {


private  ArrayList<info> info;

public Adaptor(ArrayList<info> info) {
    this.info = info;
}


public void updateList(ArrayList<info> data) {
   info = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);

         return new ViewHolder(itemView);


}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
{

    info i= info.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(i.getName());
    holder.city.setText(i.getCity());
    holder.city.setText(i.getUniversity());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return info.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name, city, uni;


    public ViewHolder(final View v) {
        super(v);
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        city = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.city);
        uni = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.university);

     }


   }

   }
```

This is my adaptor class and above is my Home activity where am trying to show my list

Comment: Paste your `"Adaptor"` code

Comment: What error it gives you ?

Comment: No adapter attached, skipping layout @Piyush

Comment: Done! I have now attached my adapter class  @jlively

Comment: post here your callstack

Comment: Try initializing your `adapter`, `recyclerview` and `layoutmanager` in `onCreate`. And then when your call in `processData` is finished get the `list` and call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: can u show me the processData method implementation in a code view ?

Comment: @RaheelSajjad take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you try to set the adapter outside of main thread. you should use this code:

```
 @Override
    public void processData(JSONArray data)
    {

        JSONObject js;

                if(data!=null)
                {
                     info=new ArrayList<>();

                    try
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++)
                        {
                            js =data.getJSONObject(i);
                            info in=new info(js.getString("Names"),js.getString("city"),js.getString("university"));
                            info.add( in);




                        }


   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myadaptor=new Adaptor(info);

                            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                            LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter( myadaptor);
           }
        });
```

Comment: where should i add this method ??

Comment: just wrap your lines `myadaptor...` by the function I gave

Comment: @RaheelSajjad i've changed my code in order to explain to you

Comment: yeah i also put your code here but it is giving me error on Home.runOnUiThread

Comment: remove 'home.' so

Comment: AppCompatActivity instance must have this method. you are doing something wrong

Comment: now it is giving me error on this line                                 recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your adapter, recyclerview and layoutmanager in onCreate. And then when your call in processData is finished get the list and call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged.

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeCallBack {

public ArrayList<info> info;
private  Adaptor myadaptor;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
    info = new ArrayList<>();
    myadaptor=new Adaptor(info);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myadaptor);

    BackgroundHome backgroundHome=new BackgroundHome(this,this);
    backgroundHome.execute();
}

@Override
public void processData(JSONArray data) {
    JSONObject js;
            if(data!=null) {
                try {
                    for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++)
                    {
                        js = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        info in = new info(js.getString("Names"),js.getString("city"),js.getString("university"));
                        info.add(in);
                    }

                    myadaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: error is i think on  onCreateViewHolder method in adapter class. see if u got it ?